# Isit possible to pass value into <div data-value="" > by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my html code

```
<div  data-percent="" ></div>
```

This is my javascript

```
 function retrieveProgressbar(){
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"retrieveprogressbar.php",
                    data:"progressbar",
                    success:function(data){
                    $(this).data("percent").html(data); 
                    }
                  });
                }

                retrieveProgressbar();
```

I need the value retrieved by ajax to be displayed in the data-percent="". I am not sure how to do that. I have another javascript that needs to use this value to execute.

Comment: Check here for examples: -> https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2):

**Need to use .attr() method.**

```
<div  data-percent="" id="datadiv"></div>

    <script>
        function retrieveProgressbar() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "retrieveprogressbar.php",
                data: "progressbar",
                success: function (data) {
                    //$("#datadiv").attr("data-percent", data);
                    // OR
                    $(this).attr("data-percent", data);
                }
            });
        }

        retrieveProgressbar();
    </script>
```

Comment: HI Sanjay, I am trying to pass a value to data-percent="" . I am not trying to retrieve from data-percent="". I believe the above is to retrieve, maybe my question was not clear. Is it possible to pass/assign value to data-percent=""??

Comment: @alexvin, let me make clear, first if we want to retrieve value then we need to write $(this).attr("data-percent"); only.No second argument but when we assign value then we have to pass second param also means $(this).attr("data-percent", data);. Let me know if you understood.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div  data-percent=""></div>
```

The proper way to **assign** `data` on jquery is

```
var new_data_value = "I will be the new value.";
$("div").data("percent",new_data_value);
```

The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

You can **retrieve** the data by:

```
var value = $( "div" ).data( "percent" );
```

---

`.attr()` on the other hand set/get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

It does not attach data of any type to DOM elements.

```
$("div").attr("data-percent",data_value);
```

Sources:
https://api.jquery.com/data/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Hi @Eddie I am trying to pass a value to data-percent="" . I am not trying to retrieve from data-percent="". I believe the above is to retrieve, maybe my question was not clear. Is it possible to pass/assign value to data-percent=""??

Comment: @alexvin I understand, You can use `.data()` to `assign` and `retrieve`... This how you assign: `$("selector").data("data-percent", "new value");`..

Comment: `$("selector").data("data-percent");`  <--- retrieve

Comment: If 2 parameters, you assign. If only one, you retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use the `.attr(` function instead.

```
$(this).attr("data-percent", your_value);
```